# How to split a large dataframe based on other dataframe values?

Tags: python, r, dataframe, split

I have two dataframes with same rownames and columnnames but in different order. values are also different.

`df1`:

```
name   S1   S2   S3   S4   S5   S6   S7
 ABC   56   67   90   78   45   34   23
 HJG   12   32   13   99   55   89   25
 KLI   88   36   95   21   66   74   45
 JHU   32   55   65   77   88   16   40
 DFR   65   90   87   11   98   67   37
```

`df2`:

```
name   S1   S3  S5   S2    S4   S7    S6
 DFR    0   -1   -1   1    -2    1    -1
 JHU    1   -2    2   1     2    0     1
 HJG   -2    0    1   1    -2   -2    -1
 ABC   -1    2   -2   1     0    1     0
 KLI    2    1    0  -1     1    0    -2
```

I want to split the `df1` dataframe into two groups based on values in `df2`.

- Group1 from `df1` should be based on values (1,2) in `df2`
- Group2 from `df1` should be based on values (-1,-2,0) in `df2`

for e.g:

```
Group1:                             Group2:

 name  S1   S3   S4                  name  S2   S5   S6  S7
 KLI   88   95   21                  KLI   36   66   74  45
```

In the same way I need to repeat for all other names also. Can anyone tell me how to do this in R or Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will give you a data frame in long form with the group markers. The code works as follows:

1. Convert both data frames from "wide" to "long" format (using `gather`), then join them (using `left_join`).
2. Create a `group` column based on the values in `df2` that you specified.
3. Remove unneeded columns
4. Sort

All of these steps are chained together using the `dplyr` pipe operator (`%>%`).

```
library(tidyverse)

df.new = df1 %>% gather(key, value, -name) %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% gather(key, value, -name), by=c("name","key"), suffix=c("1","2")) %>%
  mutate(group = ifelse(value2 >=1, "Group 1", "Group 2")) %>%
  select(name, key, value=value1, group) %>%
  arrange(group, name, key)
```

> ```
>    name key value   group
> 1   ABC  S2    67 Group 1
> 2   ABC  S3    90 Group 1
> 3   ABC  S7    23 Group 1
> ...
> 13  KLI  S1    88 Group 1
> 14  KLI  S3    95 Group 1
> 15  KLI  S4    21 Group 1
> ...
> 32  KLI  S2    36 Group 2
> 33  KLI  S5    66 Group 2
> 34  KLI  S6    74 Group 2
> 35  KLI  S7    45 Group 2
> ```

If you actually want each group in a separate data frame, you can `split` by `group` at the end of the chain, which will give you a list containing two data frames, one for each level of `group`:

```
df.list = df1 %>% gather(key, value, -name) %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% gather(key, value, -name), by=c("name","key"), suffix=c("1","2")) %>%
  mutate(group = ifelse(value2 >=1, "Group 1", "Group 2")) %>%
  select(name, key, value=value1, group) %>%
  arrange(group, name, key) %>%
  split(.$group)
```

To save the output to a `csv` or `xlsx` file:

For the first example where we have a single data frame:

```
write.csv(df.new, "file_name.csv", row.names=FALSE)

library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(df.new, "file_name.xlsx", row.names=FALSE)
```

For the second example, where we have a list containing more than one data frame, we'll write each data frame to separate csv file. For the Excel file, we'll write both data frames to different sheets in the same Excel workbook:

```
# Write to two different csv files
map(names(df.list), function(x) write.csv(df.list[[x]], paste0(x,".csv"), row.names=FALSE))

# Write to two different sheets in the same Excel file
library(xlsx)
map(names(df.list), function(x) write.xlsx(df.list[[x]], "my_file.xlsx", sheet=x, append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE))
```

Comment: I got the Group1 and Group2. But how to save them in a csv or text file? or into a data frame?

Comment: The first example already is a data frame. The second example is a list with two data frames as its elements. You just need to assign the output to an object and it will be available in your workspace. I've changed my answer to do that explicitly.